# C#: Inserting data in MySQL in UTF-8 programmatically

Tags: c#, mysql, encoding

I am writing a winforms program that gradually inserts into and reads from a MySQL database.
In PHPMyAdmin the fields I insert into are set to utf8_general_ci, and if I insert a row in the MyAdmin interface, it works perfectly. However, if I insert data on-the-fly using my program, certain special characters, like 'Ő' and 'Ű' are saved in the database as 'O' and 'U' respectively.

This is the code I am using:

```
MySqlConnection conn;
conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = sql_string;
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", conn);
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO projects (Projects_comment) VALUES (@Projects_comment)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Projects_comment", "ŐŰ");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

This however, appears as "OU" in the database. I believe the problem is with visual studio's coding. How can I change it, or how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What's the value of `sql_string`?

Comment: Server,database,port,user,password. Nothing else. Obviously, the values of these are not public. :)

Comment: Does this make any difference? https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/specifying-character-set/

Comment: Will check soon, thanks! I'll let you know if it works.